# countdown timer resume issue js

Tags: javascript, html, setinterval

I'm creating an countdown timer in js for practice. I now have a timer which counts down, pauses and you can add minutes to it.

to  resume the  timer i made a function `resumeTimer()` which should resume the timer after it is paused. however i cant figure out how to get the remaining minutes from the timer.

So far i created a variable to split the remaining minutes and seconds and I return that to the function.

When I run the `startTimer()` function again it won't resume with the remaining minutes but it will overwrite the resumed time with the starting time.

Comment: `startTime = true; if(startTime == true){` this is not necessary. The `if` will always pass.

Comment: `update()` should not be a child function of `startTimer()`. The logic of `setTimer` should not rely on text values in order to work.

Comment: `"0" + startMin + ":00"` is not ideal. You're hardcoding the leading `"0"` instead of padding with zeroes as necessary.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan i did notice that yes because now if there are 15 minutes it shows 015:00 instead of 15:00

Comment: Exactly, read about [padStart](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not have:

- a function `tick()` that can be called by `startTimer()` or `resumeTimer()`
- a variable `isTicking` which tells `tick()` whether to keep going after each second of countdown

Then you can start and stop ticking when you want.

```js
const mainDiv = document.createElement("div");
    const mainText = document.createElement("p");
    const childDiv = document.createElement("div");
    const text = document.createElement("div");
    const start = document.createElement("button");
    const minutes1 = document.createElement("button");

    mainText.innerHTML = "counter: 0";

    let countdown;

    let startTime = false;
    let startMin = 1;

    let count = 0;

    let btns = [minutes1];
    
    let time = 0;
    let isTicking = false;

    createElements();

    function createElements(){
        mainDiv.setAttribute("class", "maindiv");
        document.body.appendChild(mainDiv);

        mainText.setAttribute("class", "text");
        mainDiv.appendChild(mainText);

        childDiv.setAttribute("class", "childDiv");
        mainDiv.appendChild(childDiv);

        text.setAttribute("class", "childDiv--text");
        text.innerHTML = "0" + startMin + ":00";
        childDiv.appendChild(text);

        start.setAttribute("class", "button--start");
        start.addEventListener("click", setTimer);
        start.innerHTML = "Start";
        childDiv.appendChild(start);
    }


    /**
    * function to start the timer
    *
    */
    function startTimer(startTime){
        for(const buttons of btns){
            buttons.disabled = true;
        }

        startTime = true;

        if(startTime == true){

            /* seconds * 60 to get the minutes */
            time = startMin * 60;

            /* start the interval */
            
                tick();
        }
    }
    
    function tick() {
       countdown = setInterval(update, 1000);
             isTicking = true;
       start.innerHTML = "Pause";

            function update(){
                    if (isTicking == false) clearInterval(countdown);
                
                
                let min = Math.floor(time / 60);
                let sec = time % 60;

                /* example: show 0:09 on the timer instead of 0:9*/ 
                min = min < 10 ? "0" + min : min;
                sec = sec < 10 ? "0" + sec : sec;

                /* update the html + tab text and the remaining time */
                text.innerHTML = min + ":" + sec;
                time--;

                min == 0 && sec == 0 ? clearInterval(countdown) : countdown;

                /* show an alert when the time is expired */
                if(min == 0 && sec == 0){
                    alert("Time is up!");
                    timeOut();
                }
            }
    }


    function setTimer(){
        /* start / pause or resume the timer */ 
        if(start.innerHTML == "Pause"){  /* pause the timer */   
            pauseTimer();
        }else if(start.innerHTML == "Resume"){ /* resume the timer */   
            resumeTimer();
        }else{ /* start the timer */  
            startTimer();
        }
    }


    function pauseTimer(){
        start.innerHTML = "Resume";
        isTicking = false;
    };

    /* resume the timer with the remaining minutes + seconds */
    /* how i now have the resume */
    function resumeTimer(){ 
        tick();
    }

    /* attempt 2 to resume the timer */
    /* how i think i need to do resume */
    //function resumeTimer2() {
      //var remainingTime =  text.split(':');
        //var remainingMinAndSec = text[0] + text[1];
      // startTimer(remainingMinAndSec);
      
      //text.innerHTML = --remainingTime;
      //if (text[0] == 0 & text[1] == 0) {
         //clearInterval(countdown);
      //}
    //}
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/styles/app.css">
            <title>time practice + dom</title>
        </head>

        <body>
            <section class="time-practice" id="time-practice">
              <img src"" alt"">

            </section>
        </body>

        <script type="module" src="./resources/js/index.js"></script>
    </html>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a way i didnt think of myself. i thought the way to do it was with splitting the text and putting it in an array.

Comment: Always more than one way to skin a cat :) As a general principle though, it's a good idea to separate state and presentation... so have the simplest possible representation in memory of the state of the system (ie `isTicking`), and then worry separately about how that state looks on the screen to a user. So I wouldn't be thinking about how the clock looked while I was solving the problem of getting it to stop and start at the right time.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach to using variables in the global scope and several functions to process them would be to encapsulate all within a class. By doing this you can easily have multiple timers, all individually configurable and controllable.

The `time` is defined as a property of the class and thus becomes available to any/all methods within that class. This makes it simple to pause and restart when needed.

```js
/*
  helper class to build new dom nodes
  with attributes specified in attr.
*/
class DomNode{
  constructor( type=null, attr={}, parent=null ){
    this.type=type;
    this.attr=attr;
    this.parent=parent;
    return this.create();
  };
  create(){
    const d=document;
    this.node = this.type===null ? d.createElement( 'div' ) : d.createElement( this.type );

    let excl=[ 'text', 'textContent' ];
    for( let attr in this.attr ) {
      if( attr=='datasets' && this.attr[ attr ] instanceof Object && Object.keys( this.attr[ attr ] ).length > 0 ){
        Object.keys( this.attr[ attr ] ).forEach( name=>this.node.dataset[ name ]=this.attr[ attr ][ name ] );
      }else{
        if( this.attr.hasOwnProperty( attr ) && !~excl.indexOf( attr ) ) this.node.setAttribute( attr, this.attr[ attr ] );
      }
    }
    if( this.attr.hasOwnProperty('text') || this.attr.hasOwnProperty('textContent') )this.node.innerText=this.attr.text || this.attr.textContent;
    if( this.parent!=null ) {
      typeof( this.parent )=='object' && ( this.parent.nodeType==1 || this.parent.nodeType==11 ) ? this.parent.appendChild( this.node ) : d.getElementById( this.parent ).appendChild( this.node );
    }
    return this.node;
  };
};

/*
  Timer class to build UI for each new timer.
  Configure each independently or use default parameters.
*/
class timer{
  constructor(time=10,breaktime=2,container=false){
    this.container=container || document.body;
    this.interval=1000;
    this.breaktime=parseInt( breaktime ) * 60;
    this.time=parseInt( time ) * 60;
    this.current=this.time;
    this.def=this.time;
    this.counter=0;
    this.cycle=1;
    this.timer=NaN;
    this.messages=[
      'Times up',
      'Break is now over'
    ];
    this.createui();
  };
  createui(){
    this.parent=new DomNode(null,{'class':'maindiv'},this.container);
    this.paragraph=new DomNode('p',{'class':'text',text:'Counter:',datasets:{'counter':0}},this.parent);
    this.child=new DomNode(null,{'class':'childDiv'},this.parent);
    this.text=new DomNode(null,{'class':'childDiv--text',text:this.convert(this.time)},this.parent);

    this.btnstart=new DomNode('button',{'class':'button--start',text:'Start',datasets:{alt:'Pause',state:1}},this.child);
    this.btnrestart=new DomNode('button',{'class':'button--restart',text:'Restart'},this.child);
    this.btnminplus=new DomNode('button',{'class':'button--1Min',text:'+1 Min'},this.child);
    this.btnhrplus=new DomNode('button',{'class':'button--1hr',text:'+1 Hr'},this.child);

    this.listen();
  };
  listen(){
    /* use a single delegated listener */
    document.addEventListener('click',e=>{
      if( e.target==this.btnstart ){
        this.start(e);
        this.toggle(e);
      }
      if( e.target==this.btnrestart ){
        this.restart();
      }
      if( e.target==this.btnminplus ){
        this.current=this.time+=60;
        this.display();
      }
      if( e.target==this.btnhrplus ){
        this.current=this.time+=Math.pow(60,2);
        this.display();
      }
    });
  };
  display(){
    this.text.textContent=this.convert( this.time );
  };
  convert(time){
    const pad=(i)=>i.toString().padStart(2,'0');

    let hours=Math.floor(time/Math.pow(60,2));
    let mins=Math.floor((time-(hours*Math.pow(60,2)))/60);
    let secs=time-(hours*Math.pow(60,2))-(mins*60);

    return [
      pad(hours),
      pad(mins),
      pad(secs)
    ].join(':');
  };
  start(e){
    let el=e instanceof HTMLElement ? e : e.target;
    if( el.dataset.state==1 ){
      this.initialise( el );
      this.timer=setInterval(()=>{
        this.time--;
        this.display();
        this.timesup();
      }, this.interval );
    }else{
      clearInterval( this.timer )
    }
  };
  initialise(el){
    if( parseInt( this.current )==parseInt( this.time ) )el.dataset.tmp='Resume';
    if( !isNaN( this.timer ) )clearInterval( this.timer );              
  }
  restart(e){
    this.time=this.def;
    this.resetstate();
    this.display();
  };
  toggle(e){
    let el=e instanceof HTMLElement ? e : e.target;
    if( el.dataset.tmp!=null )el.textContent=el.dataset.tmp;
    el.dataset.state=1-el.dataset.state;
    el.dataset.tmp=el.textContent;
    el.textContent=el.dataset.alt;
    el.dataset.alt=el.dataset.tmp;
    el.removeAttribute('data-tmp');
  };
  resetstate(){
    this.btnstart.dataset.state=1;
    this.btnstart.dataset.alt='Pause';
    this.btnstart.textContent='Start';
    clearInterval( this.timer );
    this.timer=NaN;
    this.time=this.def;
    this.cycle=1-this.cycle;
  };
  announce(msg){
    console.log( msg );
  };
  timesup(){
    if( this.time <= 0 ){
      this.resetstate();
      this.increment();
      this.announce( this.messages[ this.cycle ] );
      if( this.cycle==0 ) this.displaybreaktime();
      else this.text.removeAttribute('data-label');
    }
  };
  increment(){
    this.counter++;
    this.paragraph.dataset.counter=this.counter;
  };
  disablebttns(){
    document.querySelector('.childDiv button').forEach( bttn=>bttn.disabled=true )
  };
  enablebttns(){
    document.querySelector('.childDiv button').forEach( bttn=>bttn.disabled=false )
  };
  displaybreaktime(){
    this.text.dataset.label='Breaktime';
    this.time=this.breaktime;

    this.timer=setInterval(()=>{
      this.time--;
      this.display();
      this.timesup( this.messages.brk );
    },this.interval);
  };
}//end class





    /* you can have multiple times all configured & running separately */
    const app1=new timer(1,2);      //  1 minute initial time with 2 minute break time.
    const app2=new timer(10,5);     // 10 minute initial time with 5 minute break time.
    const app3=new timer(60,15);    // 60 minute initial time with 15 minute break time.
```

```css
*{font-family:monospace}
button{margin:0.5rem;padding:1rem}
[data-counter]:after{content:attr(data-counter)}

.childDiv--text{font-size:2rem}
div[data-label]:before{content:attr(data-label)':';color:red;margin:0 0.25rem;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Call  `Date.now()` when starting the timer and store it's value in a global variable.

Call `Date.now()` again when pausing.

When substracting the first from the latter, you will get the milliseconds that have passed between those two events. With this you should be able to achieve everything you want.

Answer (score 0):

In the startTimer function, you initialize the time: let time = startMin * 60;
So when you call startTimer after Resume, time get again the initial value: (startMin * 60)
Just move that line ouside the function, like this:

```
let time = startMin * 60;

function startTimer(startTime){
    for(const buttons of btns){
        buttons.disabled = true;
    }

    startTime = true;

    if(startTime == true){
        start.innerHTML = "Pause";

        /* seconds * 60 to get the minutes */
        

        /* start the interval */
        countdown = setInterval(update, 1000);
   ....
}
```

Another useless thing is the startTime parameter that you give a value to inside the function: startTime = true;